# Migration To AndrdoidX didnt all support libraries during refracting

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, androiddesignsupport, android-appcompat

I have an issue while migrating to AndroidX. Only v4 libraries have been refracted. All other libraries have been skipped and in the layout file, I am not able to change them using the refractor method manually. I have to open each and every file to change them. Can some please guide to me what other options I am having to change them or to refract them.

Here I am attaching the code snippet for the reference and also the message what I am getting after again trying to do Migration to AndroidX from the menu.

[image: v4 libraries is migrated and not v7 or other support libraries.]

[image: Message after trying Migration to AndroidX again.]

Comment: Update your android studio to latest stable version.

Comment: @Hardik Already it is having latest version 3.4.2.